# How to express $k(x,y)=e^{x^Ty}$ as $\langle\phi(x),\phi(y)\rangle$?

Tags: inner-products

I am trying to show that $k(x,y)=e^{x^Ty}$ can be expressed as $\langle\phi(x),\phi(y)\rangle$.

I tried writing $k(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j!}(x^Ty)^j$. Now I know $(x^Ty)^j$ can be expressed as  $\langle\phi(x),\phi(y)\rangle$ since I can verify it for the case $j=1,2,3$; but I don't see the exact formula to represent $(x^Ty)^j$ so that I can "separate" $x$ and $y$. Any help?

Comment: Isn't $x^Ty$ an inner product?

Comment: Ask yourself "Is $k(x,y)$" an inner product?

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to explicitly calculate the function $\phi$ such that $k(x,y)=<\phi(x), \phi(y)>$

Comment: So I need a way to separate $x$ and $y$

Comment: "I am trying to explicitly calculate the function $\phi$ such that..."  This is not at all evident in your question.  You should edit your question to clarify what it is you are looking for.

Comment: @D_S Thanks, I edited the question. Sorry if I made a mistake in the original question using inner product.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you want to prove is false

for an actual inner product, the inner product of the zero vector with itself should be zero.